# Redirect oldsite.com/index.html to newsite.com/index

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, opencart

I know that this shouldn't be too hard to do

I wanted to know how to redirect:

```
oldsite.com/guide.html to newsite.com/guide
```

I was playing around with things, but oldsite.com/guide.html was redirecting me to newsite.com/index.php?*route*=guide.html, not newsite.com/guide 
I use opencart in this two site.

I use this code in my oldsite:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^oldsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Is that all you have in your .htaccess file? Maybe there's some other rule that rewrites and adds the "route=" part. The two conditions you posted should work as expected. I would just add the QSA modified so that query string is appended when redirect happens.

Comment: i found this too in my .htaccess
<pre>
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]

Comment: There you go. Your rewrite rules work good. But when it gets redirected to newsite.com, the new rules kick in and redirect again to ?route=...